# Left-align formatting of text column in pandas DataFrame - not working with whitespace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have created a simple pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal' :['cat', 'lion', 'zebra']})
```

When I try to style the output to left-align, this works:

```
df.style.format('{:*<6}')
```

and fills white space with *s.

This does not work:

```
df.style.format('{:<6}')
```

It returns the output right-aligned.

I want to use white space to align the text. Using a space before <6 does not work either.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Yes, set_properties works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use set_properties function?

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, set_properties works.

Comment: Thank you MhDG7.